# Is extending a base class to overwirte something an anti-pattern in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

In objective-c.

Let's say i wish to provide a custom contentview for a UICollectionView (for whatever reason it may be).

I realise the only way to achieve it is this

```
@interface UICollectionViewCell (Extension)
@property(nonatomic, readwrite)UIView *contentView;
@end

@interface BaseCollectionViewCell()

@property(nonatomic, readonly)UIView *hairuiView;

@end

@implementation BaseCollectionViewCell

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.contentView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}


@end
```

Basically, i extend the content view to be read write, such that now i can make it to be any custom view i want.

Is this considered an anti-pattern in Objective-C

Comment: It may or may not work, but I would be leery about messing with the internals of a class you don't control. Why don't you just add your custom subview to the content view and make it the same size as the content view?

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea of adding a specialized method to an existing class (`UICOllectionViewCell`) via a category is just fine.

So defining `-(UIView*)hairuiView` is cool.

However, the other stuff you're trying to do isn't cool:

(1) You cannot override a method via a category.

It's possible (although not explicitly supported) to override a method implemented in the superclass, but you cannot override a method in the class of the category.

The compiler will often allow this, but at run time only one of the methods gets implemented (either the class' original method or the one from the category), not both. And to make matters worse, there's no guarantee of which one the runtime will pick (it all depends on the order the classes are loaded).

Furthermore, `[super ...]` in the category will refer to the class's superclass, not the class you're adding the category to.

(2) You should not use an extension on classes you didn't write.

An extension is simply an anonymous category with some additional perks. However, you should only create an extension for a class that you wrote (and compile in that project). You can't add extensions to classes you don't own or have already been compiled. (Extensions allow additional instance variables to be defined and this can only be done once during compilation; you can't add instance variables to a class that's already defined/compiled.)

So stick to regular categories to extend existing classes. Category restrictions built into the language will generally keep you out of trouble—except for the override thing in (1).

This much is OK:

```
@interface BaseCollectionViewCell (HairuiView)
@property (nonatomic,readonly) UIView *hairuiView;
@end

@implementation BaseCollectionViewCell (HairuiView)

- (UIView*)hairuiView
{
    ...
}

@end
```